# Eclipse 4 RCP Deployment applicationXMI argument missing

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm trying to export an Eclipse 4 RCP application that works when I run it through Eclipse but breaks when I try and deploy it.

I found a solution to the problem [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseProductDeployment/article.html#exportproblems_checklist) but when I look at the build.properties file it does not show what is included in the export. It shows Binary Build and Source Build. I checked the Application.e4xmi file for both and it doesn't seem to have an effect.

My build.properties file looks like this:

```
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               plugin.xml,\
               Application.e4xmi,\
               icons/,\
               css/default.css
source.. = src/
jars.compile.order = .
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-02-17 09:08:01.795
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: null argument:applicationXMI argument missing
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel(E4Application.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
```

Here is my plugin.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         id="product"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
      <product
            name="GraphRCP"
            application="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application">
         <property
               name="applicationCSS"
               value="platform:/plugin/GraphRCP/css/default.css">
         </property>
         <property
               name="appName"
               value="GraphRCP">
         </property>
         <property
               name="applicationXMI"
               value="GraphRCP/Application.e4xmi">
         </property>
      </product>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

I initially had the value as `graphrcp/Application.e4xmi` this broke even launching it in Eclipse. I fixed it to `GraphRCP/Application.e4xmi` but it still won't run after export.

GraphRCP.product file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?pde version="3.5"?>

<product name="GraphRCP" uid="graphrcp" id="GraphRCP.product" application="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application" version="0.0.1" useFeatures="false" includeLaunchers="true">

   <configIni use="default">
   </configIni>

   <launcherArgs>
      <programArgs>-clearPersistedState</programArgs>
      <vmArgsMac>-XstartOnFirstThread -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts</vmArgsMac>
   </launcherArgs>

   <windowImages/>

   <launcher>
      <solaris/>
      <win useIco="false">
         <bmp/>
      </win>
   </launcher>

   <vm>
   </vm>

   <plugins>
      <plugin id="com.ibm.icu"/>
      <plugin id="my.com.jav.allinone"/>
      <plugin id="javax.annotation"/>
      <plugin id="javax.inject"/>
      <plugin id="javax.xml"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.batik.css"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.batik.util"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.batik.util.gui"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.commons.io"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.commons.lang"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.birt.jetty.overlay" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.commands"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.contenttype"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.property"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.expressions"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.aix.ppc" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.hpux.ia64_32" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.linux.ppc" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.linux.x86" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.linux.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.macosx" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.solaris.sparc" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.win32.x86" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.win32.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.jobs"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.resources"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.resources.win32.x86" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.source"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.services"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.services.source"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.di"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.source"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.services"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.source"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.cocoa"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench3"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.common"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.databinding"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.app"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.concurrent"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.ds"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.preferences"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.registry"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.util"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jface"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jface.databinding"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi.services"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.carbon.macosx" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.ppc" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.ppc64" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.s390" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.s390x" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.solaris.sparc" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.solaris.x86" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.motif.aix.ppc" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.motif.hpux.ia64_32" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.motif.linux.x86" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.motif.solaris.sparc" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.photon.qnx.x86" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.w3c.css.sac"/>
      <plugin id="org.w3c.dom.events"/>
      <plugin id="org.w3c.dom.smil"/>
      <plugin id="org.w3c.dom.svg"/>
   </plugins>


</product>
```

Comment: What is in the xxx.product file?

Comment: I added the product file in my newest edit.

Comment: Where is the GraphRCP plugin in the plugin list in the .product file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Binary build is used for the export.

This error is complaining that there is no value for the `applicationXMI` property in the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension point in the `plugin.xml`.

Something like:

```xml
<extension
     id="product"
     point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
  <product
        name="%product.name"
        application="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application">
     <property
           name="applicationXMI"
           value="your plugin id/Application.e4xmi">
     </property>
     ... other properties
  </product>
</extension>
```

Comment: I added a property with a name of applicationXMI and value of Application.e4xmi, but this didn't work. Do you know the value I should add here? Is it similar to the css value of platform:/plugin/GraphRCP/css/default.css ?

Comment: I updated my question. Still not working on export, but it appears to be working when I launch it from inside of Eclipse. Is there anything I need to add to build.properties?

Comment: Adding the GraphRCP plugin to the product file fixed it for me along with adding the extension point. Thank you so much!