# "applicationXMI parameter not set" on starting a product in Eclipse E4

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4

The last few days I took some time to shift the build process of my Eclipse E4 plugin project to maven and tycho. After I got this working I wanted to have a look at the producr again and tried to start it via RunAs "xvy.product".
I expected that to work fine, but I received this error message:

```
applicationXMI parameter not set and no branding plugin defined. 
java.lang.Exception
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.lambda$12(E4Application.java:397)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.determineApplicationModelURI(E4Application.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel(E4Application.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
```

In the end this looks, that there seems to be nothing wrong with my own code?! After a some googling I finally found some similar errors: This one was discussed here at stackoverflow [Eclipse 4 RCP Deployment applicationXMI argument missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834222/eclipse-4-rcp-deployment-applicationxmi-argument-missing), but I donot receive an 
AssertionFailedException nor do I try to export an RCP product. The other occurence was a bug at eclipse.org [Application.e4xmi should be default for "applicationXMI"](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=306623) 
As a consequence of that, I had a look at my plugin.xml and it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         id="prod"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
      <product
            application="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application"
            name="FinPim">
         <property
               name="appName"
               value="FinPim">
         </property>
         <property
               name="applicationXMI"
               value="mhFinPim/Application.e4xmi">
         </property>
         <property name="lifeCycleURI" value="bundleclass://mhFinPim/de.mho.finpim.lifecycle.Manager"></property>
      </product>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

You can see here, that my applicationXMI points to mhFinPim/Application.e4xmi
, which is bundlename/Applicatione4xmi
So, now I wonder, what else might be wrong that prevents my procuct from starting?

Subsequent to this exception, I receive a further one:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI$URIPool$PlatformAccessUnit.setValue(URI.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI$URIPool.intern(URI.java:1949)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI.createPlatformPluginURI(URI.java:2718)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.determineApplicationModelURI(E4Application.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel(E4Application.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
```

I suppose, this is just a subsequent error, caused by the first exception?

Comment: Possibly that isn't the plugin.xml you are running. Check the Run Configuration.

Comment: Awkward enough, the Run Configuration really didn't point to the mentioned plugin.xml! ;-(

Answer (score 0):

I got the same type of error when I accidently regenerated my eclipse.ini file after a rebuild. My problem at that occasion was that the reference (-vm) to the Java VM had been deleted in the ini file.